# ee.Image.sampleRegions - what does the geometries parameter do?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geemap, samplepoints

I am reading the geemap tutorial and I have question about the [sampleRegions](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-sampleregions) function. As I understand, this function "cross" between vector data (feature collection) and a given raster, and generates new feature collection with the pixel value for each point.
However, I don't understand what is the geometries parameter is for:

[image: "]

**isn't it suppose by deafult to include point geometry per pixel? why wouldn't it? which geometries will be omitted? not sure I understand how to use this parameter and how it works.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `false`, the features in the resulting feature collection will not include the geometry of their corresponding region, only the sampled band values.

A very common use-case where you don't need to include the geometry is when you are creating a training data-set for a classifier. The classifier only cares about the band values and the class:

```
var trainingData = image.sampleRegions({
  collection: referenceData, 
  scale: 10, 
  geometries: false // We don't need the geometries here
})

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(5)
  .train(trainingData, 'value')
var classification = image.classify(classifier)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/846e1fc668ec69677c03b172e5603d83